# Inserir caracteres especiais em mysql e puxar esses valores idênticos na aplicação web

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Boa noite, Preciso adicionar valores ao banco de dados pelo mysql de forma que eles possuam caracteres especiais. Eu consigo adicionar, mas não consigo puxar os valores corretamente, eles acabam que vindo com símbolos no lugar dos caracteres especiais, por exemplo...

Informática
Inform�tica

Comment: Os dois charset estão iguais. Mas mesmo assim o problema persiste.

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta da pergunta linkada no comentário, lá fala a respeito disso e mostra varias soluções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Certifique-se de que no banco de dados os valores estão corretos (com acentuação).
- Você não especificou qual linguagem está usando, porém pelas tags acredito que seja PHP. Configure o charset das páginas corretamente. Ex:

  `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');`

Comment: Sim, sim php. O charset está correto.

Comment: Qual charset está usando?

Comment: Estou usando UTF-8

Comment: Altere para ISO-8859-1

Comment: Okay, deu certo, mas agora a página toda está vindo com simbolos diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma, Obrigado Fabiano Lira, Gato.

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```